# pyspark split csv with spaces in string - jupyter notebook

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**I do not want to read a text file**, I want to perform the action over an **existing Dataframe**

my DataFrame has only one column text, like a file, *"tabSeparator"*.

It is a **structured** file, with 3 columns, **separator** is a *tab*.
In case the *column* has an embedded *tab*, it is enclosed in double quotes (`"xxx xx"`)

Example:

```
-------------------------
col_0
-------------------------
c11   c12    c13
c21 c22 c23   
"c 31" "c 32" c33
```

I am using this **regular expression**: 
I am using **pyspark** with **Jupyter Notebook**

```
myre = '([\\t ]?(\\".*?\\"|[^\\t ]+))'

df = textDF.withColumn("tmp", split( col("_c0"), myre))\
      .select(\
        col("tmp").getItem(0).alias("col_1"),\
        col("tmp").getItem(1).alias("col_2"),\
        col("tmp").getItem(2).alias("col_3")
      )
```

Not sure if the problem is with the regular expression or my way to parse the file but I cannot create a new DataFrame with the 3 columns parsed, **resulting** on:

```
-------------------
|col_1|col_2|col_3|
------+-----+------
| c11 | c12 | c13 |
| c21 | c22 | c23 |  
| c 31| c 32| c 33|
-------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing that csv reader cannot handle:

```
spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(path_to_file)
```

In Spark 2.3 you can done on existing distribute data structure:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    'c11\tc12\tc13', 'c21\tc22\tc23', '"c\t31"\t"c\t32"\t"c\t33"'
], "string").toDF("col_0")


spark.read.option('delimiter', '\t').csv(df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.col_0)).show()


# +----+----+----+
# | _c0| _c1| _c2|
# +----+----+----+
# | c11| c12| c13|
# | c21| c22| c23|
# |c    31|c    32|c    33|
# +----+----+----+
```

UDF with `csv` might work in 2.2 with Python 3 but it will be slow:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import csv

@udf("struct<c0:string,c1:string,c2:string>")
def csv_(s):
    try:
        return next(csv.reader([s], delimiter="\t"))
    except: pass

df.select(csv_("col_0").alias("tmp")).select("tmp.*").show()

# +----+----+----+
# |  c0|  c1|  c2|
# +----+----+----+
# | c11| c12| c13|
# | c21| c22| c23|
# |c    31|c    32|c    33|
# +----+----+----+
```

Answer (score -1):

Obviously the problem that you have is that there are two possible separators.

With DataFrames it is very simple to load files with only one separator, for example tab separators, they are considered like CSV files but instead of a comma, it is just a tab.

In this particular scenario you would read them like this:

yourDF = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv('/tabSeparator/')

But if you have multiple, I believe the only option is to use a regex. You could use RDDs too and write a longer function and use map.

Comment: I have already one dataframe with only ONE column! The question was how to parse it and create 3 columns. You can assume that tab is the only separator. I do not want to read the file as you suggest because it does not exists.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, just trying to help :) If you read the last part you could see that there is an option for using an RDD and doing a simple split by tab but you could use a SerDe for the quotes.